# Obtaining the relations of variables using diagonal matrices

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I know this is too an elementary question, but I am a pathetic newbie in mathematica and I cannot find any answer by googling.

What I want is obtaining some relations of unknown variables using their restrictions, which are given by

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k}A_{ik}A_{jk}=0, \qquad A_{ij}=-A_{ji}    
\end{equation}
where $(i,j,k)$ are from 1 to 6.
These are, of course, represented as matrix forms by
\begin{equation}
AA^T=0, \qquad A^T=-A.
\end{equation}
And I need to obtain some relations of $A_{ij}$'s, e.g., $A_{25}A_{15}+A_{45}A_{35}$, from these matrix equation. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Hi ! Is it just me or your LaTeX code isn't showing up correctly on my screen ?

Comment: I see the latex correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want. But check whether the following is what you want. 
For simplicity, I consider the case for the dimension 3, however you can simply change `dim = 6` for your needs.

```
dim = 3;
mat = Array[a, {dim, dim}]; 
% // MatrixForm

mat2 = ReplacePart[ 
   mat, { {i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} /; i > j  :>   - a[j, i]} ];
% // MatrixForm

# == 0 & /@ ( mat2. Transpose[mat2] // Flatten) // TableForm
```

The answer looks like

```
a[1,2]^2+a[1,3]^2==0
a[1,3] a[2,3]==0
-a[1,2] a[2,3]==0
a[1,3] a[2,3]==0
a[1,2]^2+a[2,3]^2==0
a[1,2] a[1,3]==0
-a[1,2] a[2,3]==0
a[1,2] a[1,3]==0
a[1,3]^2+a[2,3]^2==0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
A.A == 0
A == -Transpose[A]
```

See [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixOperations.html) for details.